# DELETE Http Method takes forever and might timeout on WebApi

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I cant really find an explanation for this, im sending a DELETE request to this API end point, my code is very simple:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteSize(int id) {

        Size size;

        try {

            size = db.Sizes.First(q => q.ID == id);
            size.Deleted = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, size);
    }
```

However on the Azure staging server it takes forever to respond, it works very fast locally but not sure what happends when it is on a remote server, what might be the reason for this ?, all other calls GET/POST/PULL responds in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the problem was that i was returning the db model in the Request.CreateResponse, probably has something to do with dbContext